# Elementary OS - Stop MySQL from starting automatically at boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

MySQL is started automatically each time I boot my ElementaryOS Luna, how can I disable this and have MySQL off by default?

I have verified that the `mysql` service is disabled at all runlevels using `chkconfig --list` but every time I restart the machine mysql responds normally, i.e. it is running, and I have to run `sudo service mysql stop` to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu so I would have a look through the  `/etc/rc`
directories and see if there is an entry in there which is starting mysql

The Ubuntu guide for this sort of thing suggests something along these lines:

```
rm /etc/rc*/*myscript
```

where 'myscript' is the service you want to stop starting at boot